# Answer call using TAPI3 C#

Tags: tapi

I'm stuck in TAPI programming. I've created a program to monitor activity of phone call. Everything is working fine, but now I want to implement a functionality to accept and reject a call from web directly.

i have registered a line with both monitor and owner priviledge but still when i debug my program the ici (ITCallInfo object) shows me priviledge as "1" which means i only have monitor rights not owner. am i doing anything wrong, please help me out. Thanks in advance

```
try
    {
        ec.Next(1, out ici, ref arg);
        if (ici != null && ici.CallState == CALL_STATE.CS_OFFERING)
        {
            ITBasicCallControl2 bc = (TAPI3Lib.ITBasicCallControl2)ici;
            if (bc != null)
            {
                bc.Answer();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For which MediaType did you register your lines? It Should be done for MediaType Audio, if you're dealing with simple phone calls.

Also, make soure your PBX is configured in a way, which allows you to have owner rghts for a given Line.
the `RegisterCallNotifications` does not set owner rights directly, it will ask the PBX to get owner rights, but if you're not allowed to have them, you'll never going to be able to register your line with owner rights.

see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms732558(v=vs.85).aspx for further information.